# Firing Toast Not working as expected

Tags: apex, lightning-aura-components

I am trying to understand how I can handle response from the Apex Class in to the lightning component Controller. The Apex Class is like below where I am trying to check the Account Id of the Case and show a toast through lightning component

```
public class updateCaseRecord {    
  @AuraEnabled
    public static String passCase(String caseId){
        List<Case> case_recs = [SELECT id,AccountId,Status,Subject from Case WHERE Id = :caseId];
        String returnString;
        for (Case rec : case_recs)
        {
            if (rec.AccountId == '001U000001OgQ0OIAV')
            {
                returnString = 'Assign an actual account to the case.';
            }}
        //update case_recs;      
        return returnString;
    }}
```

I am trying to fire a toast with the lightning component like below

```
passCaseToCS_helper: function(c,e,h) {
    var set_action = c.get("c.passCase");
    set_action.setParams({caseId: c.get('v.recordId')});
    set_action.setCallback(this, result => {
        $A.get("e.force:showToast")
        .setParams({
        type: 'error',
        message: result.returnString,
        mode: 'pester'
    }).fire();
    $A.get("e.force:refreshView").fire();
});
$A.enqueueAction(set_action);       
}})
```

Also tried the other way like

```
({passCaseToCS_helper: function(c,e,h) {
    var set_action = c.get("c.passCase");
    set_action.setParams({caseId: c.get('v.recordId')});
    set_action.setCallback(this, function(response) {
        var state = response.getState();
        if(component.isValid() && state === "SUCCESS"){
            var resultFormApex = response.getReturnValue();
            var toastEvent = $A.get("e.force:showToast");
            toastEvent.setParams({
                message: resultFormApex,
                type: "error"
            });
            toastEvent.fire();    
        }});
$A.enqueueAction(set_action);   
}})
```

Both the ways when I click the button on the case that has AccountId '001U000001OgQ0OIAV' nothing happens it just refreshes the page with no toast on it. I am not sure if I am missing something here.

Comment: if(component.isValid() && state === "SUCCESS") => if(c.isValid() && state === "SUCCESS")

Comment: @kurunve I changed fromponent to c.isVaild() but it didnt work

Comment: Where are you running this Lightning component?